# solution for missing ground wire from main Breaker

Tags: grounding

I have two sub panels. The first sub panel is fed by the main panel.  The 2nd sub panel is fed by the first sub panel. The main and 1st sub were replacements from FPE panels.

My situation is complicated because the 1st sub panel is being fed by only three wires from the main. However it has a ground rod instead of a ground wire from the main panel. The second sub panel is fed from the larger 1st sub panel, fortunately it is being by four wires from the 1st sub panel.

Originally the second sub panel was fed with only three wires from the main panel. That circuit is now deleted, the wire is still there but not connected on either end.

Can one of those deleted wires which run from the main to the second sub be re-purposed as a ground wire? Green tape would be liberally applied on both ends to Identify it as a ground. Of course making sure it was of adequate size.

The next step would be to splice a wire of the same size and run it a short distance to the 1st sub panel which is close. It's a lot closer than going all the way back to the main on the other side of the house. The two sub panels are virtually on top of each other, one is upstairs from the other.  Bottom line is that the ground wire from the main to the 1st sub panel would be a spliced wire that runs through the 2nd sub panel enclosure.

Hopefully I've detailed this situation enough to be understandable. There may be a NEC rule about the ground wire needing to be in the same sheath or raceway as the the feeder from the main. Might probably be a rule about splicing ground wires too.

Comment: Are any of these connections in conduit or are they armored cables or non metallic cables?

Comment: Most likely ground is on metallic conduit you have not mentioned. [Edit] tp provide pictures.

Comment: There's probably a rule about re-identifying a power wire into a ground wire.